# Can't insert data into MySQL using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

i am new with all the php and my sql. 
and i have problem whith the insert data to mysql. 
the code run good including the connection to the database but in the act of the insert data nothing happened. mysql is in host server.
what it can be?
this is part of my code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pw = "password";
$db = "database";
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);
if (!$link) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "INSERT INTO lids (sireal, first_name, face_name, telephone, age, email, date) VALUES (null,'$first_name','$face_name','$telephone','$age','$from','$date')";
mysqli_query($link,$query); 
mysqli_close($link);
header('Location:http://www.ttttt/?mess=1 ');
exit;
```

Comment: Use prepared statements, check the database error, `mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link);` and comment the line of `header()` only for tests!

Comment: and those VALUES' variables are defined *where* exactly?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Variables started to appear and then there was *Magic in the Kingdom*. Ticks... those are for flea bitten varmins. *Aren't they Sam?*

Comment: I don't want to seem like one of those guys but are you initiating the variables?

Comment: Hi @Ben. Is Column 'sireal' Primary Key And Auto-incremented ? If Yes, Then why passing NULL to it.

Comment: Hi @Ben. I'll take just a bit of cream in my coffee, *thanks*. Give us a call when you've gotten back from *who knows where*.

Comment: first thanks for the fast retreat .

Comment: the variables are defined in the code that i don't pasted here.

Comment: and yes the soreal is Primary Key And Auto-incremented  and i saw in some tutorial to di this

Comment: hi Nana Partykar so what should i pass if it is Primary Key and Auto-incremented?

Comment: You were told what to do in comments in order to check for errors. It seems you haven't done that, otherwise you would have told us what the errors were. Post your db schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the ticks on your column names on the insert query. Also whenever you run a database query, make sure to include the error handling, e.g die(mysql_error()) for error definitions relating to mysql or mysqli.

Comment: ticks, oh, why? plus, this is really a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake seems here with null value you are inserting, have u defined in table structure so that serial can accept null values.

```
You haven't even assigned values to your variable you are using in insertion .
You can declare them and can assign values as before the query.
$first_name="test";
$face_name="john";
$telephone=566777888;
$age = 26;
$from = 'test@example.com';
```

Comment: and simplest way to debug if query is executing or not, simply echo mysqli_query($link,$query); if its displays 1 on the screen its executed successfully.